# Rapidminer - unable to apply learning algorithm as process document is making regular to text

Tags: machine-learning, rapidminer

have the following process :

1. **Process documents from files**  (where I load the  text files with respective 6 classes ) --> this connects to **set Role** (which changes text attribute to REGULAR attribute to allow machine learning)   -> **Process documents from data** ( I dont need the word vectors so I uncheck that, I keep text, within this process I tokenize, stopwords, stemming etc.)  and then I feed this into **validation** operator. (bayes/svm)

What is happening here is in the example set the ***text column*** is going back to type "TEXT" from ***regular*** after running Process documents from Data. And hence I get the error ***Input ExampleSet has no attributes*** as there are zero regular attributes. And this is causing the process to fail. I have no idea why. I try to set the role ***again*** after this but then the error says "***No examples in example set"***

PLEASE HELP. I am stuck since two days!!!

**EDIT : I think I know the issue - I was applying  a 10-fold X-Validation on a dataset with few examples**

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the issue :

I was applying a 10-fold X-Validation on a dataset with very few examples